# Live Preview: Hide tabs from live preview

Tags: live-preview

I've noticed that Live Preview mode includes fields from **all** tabs. Is it possible to specify tabs to be left out of the Live Preview display?

For example, if you have an 'SEO' tab which consists of meta data it's not relevant to include this in the Live Preview mode whilst constructing the page. With lots of tabs this just becomes confusing for the user when only a few of them are relevant.

Is there a way to exclude set tabs or fields?

Comment: Good suggestion, Ian! I'd suggest you make this a feature request and post the link here. Thanks!

Comment: Done. :) http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/9408984-hide-tabs-and-fields-from-live-preview

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no out-of-the-box way to do that.

You *might* be able to pull it off with something like the [CP-CSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) plugin, but I'm not sure how you'd just target the tab when the Live Preview pane is open.

Otherwise, you can always make a [feature request](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues)!

Comment: Brad, I'm aware this question is quite old so I just wanted to ask if as of 2017 there are any plans for Live Preview to include the tabs in the same way that the 'regular edit mode' does? I _love_ live preview, and it is actually one of the primary reasons we switched to Craft a couple of years ago, but not having the tabs there makes the interface feel really quite confusing if the tabs have been specifically used to separate content, especially if there is a super long matrix type field in one of them. Thanks! :)

Comment: @MikeVaux you should consider thumbs-up/commenting on https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/969

Comment: Thanks Brad! I've thumbs up'd #948 (https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/948), as that more accurately describes what I'd love to see :)